# Remove border from buttons CSS?

Tags: css, border, padding

Have some share buttons at the bottom with a border (padding?) I don't want in this [Website](http://www.stenza.com.mx).

The only thing my template service provider allows me in the code is to include CSS.

This is the solution I arrived to with my limited knowledge (but not working):

```
.fa {
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 30px;
    width: 14px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: none;
}
```

Would you suggest any solution with a line code that could help?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try using .fa{border:0} ??

Comment: Are you talking about  the twitter / facebook buttons?

Comment: It had to do with padding to avoid space in between buttons!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the inspector, you get that from the padding of `.site-footer .btn`
Include this CSS in your code.

```
.site-footer .btn {
    padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

How about removing the border with:

```
.fa {
     border: 0;
}
```

Or you could use `border-style: 0` instead.

Working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/faukdmvr/3/).  You can find a tutorial on the use of border [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_border.asp)

Comment: It had to do with padding to avoid space in between buttons!

Answer (score 0):

If your mean the twitter / facebook framework buttons, try this:

```
.site-footer .btn-default,
.site-footer .btn-default:hover {
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: It had to do with padding to avoid space in between buttons!